# WebGL-How to get the normals data of the texture for post-processing of edge detection

Tags: shader, webgl, edge-detection

When I was looking for the WebGL edge detection method, 
I saw that Unity has a solution. Use Camera-DepthNormalTexture.shader to write the depth and normals data to the texture. 
I will use the Roberts operator to calculate whether the obtained data is an edge, 
but WebGL i can only get depthTexture in framebuffer, 
can not get depthNormalTexture like in unity, 
I tried to write a test in WebGL, 
only use the depthtexture obtained in framebuffer, 
but only detect edges with huge depth differences, 
and Cannot detect all the edges of the solid color model. 
I want to know if there are other ways to solve this kind of problem.

[(solid color)WebGL test  rendering pic][1]

[image]

I set the normal data of the vertex in advance

Using the shader provided in gman's answer, get the texture of normals data in framebuffer in a new rendering. The result seems to draw edges, but the depth seems to be wrong

```
framebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
// rgb texture
gl.bindTexture(state.gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
// ... texImage2D  texParameteri set up
// depth texture
gl.bindTexture(state.gl.TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture);
// ... texImage2D  texParameteri set up


// Create a with normals data FBO
normalFramebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, normalTexture);
// ... texImage2D  texParameteri set up


gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
 obj.render('rgbaData shader');
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, normalFramebuffer);
 obj.render('normalsData shader');
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
gl.useProgram('my edge detection shader');
gl.uniform1i(texture, 0);
gl.uniform1i(depthTexture, 1);
gl.uniform1i(normalTexture, 2);
```

Comment: did you add a depth buffer to your normalFramebuffer? The article linked in my answer shows how to do that.

Comment: @gman yeah..I added depthbuffer in normal framebuffer, it worked perfect. wow..awesome..great..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity generates the texture with normals even in WebGL so this is not a limit of WebGL. If you want a texture with normals then render a texture with normals.

Assuming you have geometry data with normals then you'd use a vertex shader something like

```
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec3 normal;

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 modelView;
uniform mat4 normalMatrix;

varying vec3 v_normal;

void main() {
  gl_Position = projection * modelView * position;
  v_normal = mat3(normalMatrix) * normal;
}
```

and a fragment shader like

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec3 v_normal;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(normalize(v_normal) * 0.5 + 0.5, gl_FragCoord.z);
}
```

And [render your shapes to a texture via a framebuffer](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-render-to-texture.html). You then have a texture with normals and depth in it which you can pass to your check edge shader

You can read more about shaders with normals [here](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-lighting-directional.html)

Comment: Also fyi: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhGjCzxJV3E

Comment: it turned out that I was caught in a misunderstanding, I always thought that the normals data need to pass through like get depth 
just like this   gl.framebufferTexture2D(state.gl.FRAMEBUFFER, state.gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, state.gl.TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture, 0)           
Now I figure it out, thank you very much      ps: Sometimes the geometry data does not contain the corresponding normal data, I still need to search how to generate these data, of course, this is another problem, thanks again

Comment: you can [generate normals in the fragment shader using standard derivatives](https://www.enkisoftware.com/devlogpost-20150131-1-Normal-generation-in-the-pixel-shader). In webgl1 you have to [check for and enable the extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/OES_standard_derivatives/) and put `#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable` at the top of the shader.

Comment: I got the texture with normal data according to your method, but after taking the final edge calculation into account, the rendered texture seems to have edges that should not be rendered. I don't know what's wrong,plz take a look,thx

Answer (score 0):

> *"WebGL’s You can only get depthTexture in framebuffer, you can not get depthNormalTexture [...]"*

Depth textures are supported in [WebGL 2.0](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/) or by the extension [WEBGL_depth_texture](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/WEBGL_depth_texture/) is supported. Evaluate if the extension is supported:

```js
if (!gl.getExtension("WEBGL_depth_texture"))
    alert('"WEBGL_depth_texture" not supported');
```

See further [WebGL 1.0 5.14.14 Detecting and enabling extensions](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#5.14.14)

Comment: Thanks, I've got the depthTexture, but the edge detection algorithm in unity I saw needs to obtain depth and normal data for each pixel in the texture, and it seems that just depth data is not enough...or expect a better way to achieve solid color objects Edge detection

Comment: @GINKO [WEBGL_draw_buffers](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/WEBGL_draw_buffers/) provides multiple draw buffers and [OES_texture_float](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/OES_texture_float/) provides floating point textures (see also [WebGL Extension Registry](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/)). Hency you can implement a complet G-buffer

Comment: Unity is to directly call the interface to get the relevant information. WebGL has read your information here, and has a general understanding. I don't know how to use it. Is there any relevant example for reference